# Unit testing controllers with annotations

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my controllers in a Spring MVC web app. I have already got a fairly comprehensive set of unit tests for the domain model, but for completeness I want to test the controllers too.

The issue I'm facing is trying to test them without loading a Spring context. I thought I could get around this with mocking, but the method in the controller has a @Transactional annotation which attempts to open a transaction (and fails with a NullPointerException because no Spring context is loaded).

Code example:

```
public class UsersController {

  @Autowired private UserManager userManager;

  @Transactional
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView create(User user) {

    userManager.save(user);

    ModalAndView mav = new ModelAndView();    
    mav.addObject("user", user);
    mav.setViewName("users/view");
    return mav;
  }

}
```

So essentially I want to test the behaviour without loading a context and actually persisting the user.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Cheers,

Caps

Comment: Maybe you have the Spring test runner specified on your test? Otherwise @Transactional shouldn't cause the test to fail.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for that! Feel free to put that as the answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say mocking is the way to go here. The `@Transactional` annotation will have no effect unless there is a Spring context loaded and instructed to configure annotation-based transactions.

Make sure that you **aren't** instructing JUnit to run your test within a spring context by specifying something like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:spring/ITestAssembly.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

To prevent confusion, I keep my unit tests (not running in a spring context) in separate files than my integration tests. Typically all mocking occurs in the unit tests and not in integration tests.

Comment: Yep I've pulled out the spring context and mocked the UserManager and all is good.

Answer (score 1):

The `NullPointerException` occurs not because of the `Transactional`, but because nothing gets injectedas `UserManager`. You have two options:

- run with the spring test runner
- mock the `userManager` and set it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've gone with the second option.